# Porting Ubuntu Touch On Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, android, development

Can i port Ubuntu Touch on samsung galaxy s2 plus i9105p?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official list of supported devices is available at:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Even if [i9100](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9100) seems to be the closest device, the chipset here is a `Samsung Exynos 4210 / ARM Cortex-A9` where for your i9105p the chipset is a `Broadcom BC28155 / ARM Cortex-A9` ([Source](http://www.morecellphone.com/compare/phones/samsung-galaxy-s2-plus-gt-i9105-vs-samsung-galaxy-s2-gt-i9100-16gb/216184)).

So unless your device is listed on the wiki page, I'd say that is not (yet) supported.